# Sidebar moving when hovering over a nav button

Tags: css, html

I have a nav bar with buttons that raise when you hover over them. The problem is the content also raises with it. Its as if the content won't stay static with its container. I'm using z-index so a lot of the positioning has to be relative, but playing around with other positioning doesn't seem to help. This has been driving me nuts. Any suggestions?

*Link removed for privacy, or whatever*

I'm linking directly to the full page to show the full problem. Sorry if there's a rule against that; I'm new here.

Also, its not finished yet and the code is really sloppy so, you know, don't judge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the HTML for your nav is invalid. You've got anchor tags wrapping list items. You're also doing a lot of tricks with negative margins because of floated elements. It would be better to add overflow:hidden; onto your `nav ul` and actually get those elements back into the viewport.

However, to quickly fix your issue, you need to clear your content so it won't be affected by the positioning going on in your nav. See below.

```
#content {
    clear: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly.

As for the anchor tags, whats the proper way to do it?

Edit: Nevermind. Stupid question.
Thanks again for sifting through my ugly code. I was trying a few new things, ran into problems, made impromptu fixes. I'm a little embarrassed I had to show it to people, haha